# Why is anti-siphon leaking with just one zone?

Tags: irrigation, sprinkler-system

About a month ago I started to notice that the anti-siphon leaks or seems like it is trying to pressurize like it would when turning the system on in the spring. As far as I can tell this only happens with one zone. It only lasts a second or two until it seals. Any idea why this happens and what is my solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to guess, but most probable cause: the anti-siphon is installed in the wrong place. Is it 6" above any other opening in the same zone? Check manuals, maybe your should be 12" (or 18").

Do you have a filter somewhere? If not, maybe some grain of rot or sand is entered on syphon and it make is more difficult to close.

Or there is a problem in your zone. Anti-siphon need pressure to close, maybe there is some leak in the zone, or you attached too many springers, so water has difficult to get on right pressure, and so it take time to close the anti-siphon valve.

Try to exchange the anti-siphon, from the leaking zone to an other zone (and contrary) and test. This could give you hints if it is something in the line or the anti-siphon.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The strange thing is that it wasn’t happening at the start of the season and doesn’t always happen.

Comment: pipes moves (especially when you give them pressure). It could be that you are at limit of pressure (so also temperature, and amount of water already in pipes) could have effects. But it difficult to guess. There are many reasons. You should start to debug (make notes) to find what it is faulty.